# Tagging searching for previous tags, while allowing for new tags to be accepted

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tagging

I'm looking for a jQuery plug-in that works the way tagging works on [Last.fm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last.fm).

Tagging on Last.fm, uses an autosuggest to find previous tags and recommend them. If you select one of these tags, it updates the CSS like [Facebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook) so it has a bubble around it with an X.

Tags are seperated with a comma: `,`

For tags entered that are new and not found in the autosuggest, if you type in 'adsadsasd' and then enter a comma, that text is then wrapped in the same style as above on Last.fm.

Anyone know of any plug-ins that will do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice new jQuery Plugin which will even place an image around each tag and add a remove button.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tag-it